# View Perl Variables as Bytes/Bits

Tags: perl, binary

Disclaimer: It's been ages since I've done any perl, so if I'm asking/saying something stupid please correct me.

Is it possible to view a byte/bit representation of a perl variable?  That is, if I say something like

```
my $foo = 'a';
```

I know (think?) the computer sees `$foo` as something like

```
0b1100010
```

Is there a way to get perl to print out the binary representation of a variable?

(Not asking for any practical purpose, just tinkering around with a old friend and trying to understand it more deeply than I did in 1997)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, using [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html):

```
print unpack "B*", $foo;
```

Example:

```
% perl -e 'print unpack "B*", "bar";'
011000100110000101110010
```

The perldoc pages for [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) and [perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html) give a nice overview about converting between different representations.

Comment: i just realized, in 2017 perl has out of the box ascii to binary conversion. neat! I don't know another language that has that.

Answer (score 2):

The place to start if you want the actual internals is a document called "perlguts".  Either `perldoc perlguts` or read it here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html

Comment: an interesting take in the question, I have followed up with a note on Devel::Peek

Answer (score 2):

After seeing the way that Andy interpreted your question, I can follow up by saying that [Devel::Peek](http://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aPeek) has a `Dump` function which can show the internal representation of a variable. It won't take it to the binary level, but if what you are interested in is the internals, you might look at this.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e 'my $foo="a";Dump $foo';
SV = PV(0x7fa8a3004e78) at 0x7fa8a3031150
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x7fa8a2c06190 "a"\0
  CUR = 1
  LEN = 16

$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e 'my %bar=(x=>"y",a=>"b");Dump \%bar'
SV = IV(0x7fbc5182d6e8) at 0x7fbc5182d6f0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,ROK)
  RV = 0x7fbc51831168
  SV = PVHV(0x7fbc5180c268) at 0x7fbc51831168
    REFCNT = 2
    FLAGS = (PADMY,SHAREKEYS)
    ARRAY = 0x7fbc5140f9f0  (0:6, 1:2)
    hash quality = 125.0%
    KEYS = 2
    FILL = 2
    MAX = 7
    RITER = -1
    EITER = 0x0
    Elt "a" HASH = 0xca2e9442
    SV = PV(0x7fbc51804f78) at 0x7fbc51807340
      REFCNT = 1
      FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
      PV = 0x7fbc5140fa60 "b"\0
      CUR = 1
      LEN = 16
    Elt "x" HASH = 0x9303a5e5
    SV = PV(0x7fbc51804e78) at 0x7fbc518070d0
      REFCNT = 1
      FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
      PV = 0x7fbc514061a0 "y"\0
      CUR = 1
      LEN = 16
```

Answer (score 2):

And one more way:

```
printf "%v08b\n", 'abc';
```

output:

```
01100001.01100010.0110001
```

(The v flag is a perl-only printf/sprintf feature and also works with numeric formats other than `b`.)

This differs from the unpack suggestion where there are characters greater than `"\xff"`: unpack will only return the 8 low bits (with a warning), `printf '%v...'` will show all the bits:

```
$ perl -we'printf "%vX\n", "\cA\13P\x{1337}"'
1.B.50.1337
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ord` to return the numeric value of a character, and `printf` with a `%b` format to display that value in binary.

```
print "%08b\n”, ord 'a'
```

**output**

```
01100010
```